# Using https in combination with @Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, https, html.beginform

I have a mvc4 view form with some fields, let's say:

- User name
- Surname
- Age
- Code

below an example:

```
@{
      var actionURL = "https://"  + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

  using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Configure", FormMethod.Post), new { @action = actionURL })
  {
    ...
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserViewModel.Name, null, new { id = "UserName" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.UserViewModel.UserCode, new { id = "UserCode" })

    ...

    <input id="submitUser" type="submit" value="Send" />

    ...
  }
```

}

**ConfigureController.cs:**

```
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult AddUser(UserViewModel model)
    {
        // Encrypt user code and store it in database
        // Store in database the rest of user information as-is, without encrypting
    }
```

Code field should be encrypted once user info is submited through internet but other fields are not necessary. Then once I recieve user info in the controller, I encrypt the code field and store it in the database. Other user information is stored in database as-is.

I want to encrypt the user code in server side not in client side.

My problem is that once submit button is clicked an error is thrown, a page is shown saying:

- Ensure web address https://... is correct
- Search the page with you search engine
- Update/Refresh the page in a few minutes
- Ensure TLS/SSL protocols are enabled by going to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced options->Configuration->Security

I have ensured that TLS and SSL protocols are enabled: SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 are enabled.

What's wrong? and how to send code encrypted to the mvc4 controller? I do not want to make changes in web.config.

I have tried other solutions like explained below, but nothing works for me:

building own action filter: [ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574347/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps)

using form action instead of html.beginform:
[How to change POST to SSL URL in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751742/how-to-change-post-to-ssl-url-in-mvc-4)

but nothing works...

Comment: make sure that both your View ( GET ) and your Processor ( POST ) have the RequireHttps.   Looks like your POST requires it, but your GET does not

Comment: @davethecoder How to check that? and how to do that? could you explain me more detailed please?